# Parsing JSON in Kendo UI Window control

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, json, kendo-ui

I am having a controller action that returns a JSON as below.I dont get any errors. If i  populate static data it is shown in the window.

```
public ActionResult Reader()
        {

            return Json(new 
            {
                ReaderName = "First Floor",
                Cardholder = "John, Doe",
            });
        }
```

Now I have a kendo UI window in the client side to which i want to populate this data from the action. **AM I doing something wrong because i am not able to parse this data to the window.** The template does not seem to work!
Below is the client side code.

```
wnd = $("#details")
                        .kendoWindow({
                            title: "Reader Name",
                            modal: false,
                            visible: false,
                            resizable: false,
                            width: 300,
                            content: {
                                url: "/List/Reader",
                                dataType: "json",
                                template:"ReaderName #=ReaderName#"

                            }

                        }).data("kendoWindow");
```

Comment: Do you get any errors? Have you checked to see the if the server is returning the correct response using a console? MVC tends to require the AJAX request has the correct headers in order to return JSON

Comment: @Blade0rz: I checked using fiddler. Looks like the JSON GET Request was blocked. Once i set the jsonrequestbehaviour it started working. Anyway thanks.If you could post it as an answer i would vote it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To return JSON from a GET request in ASP.NET MVC, you need to specify the JsonRequestBehaviour:

```
public ActionResult Reader()
        {

            return Json(new 
            {
                ReaderName = "First Floor",
                Cardholder = "John, Doe",
            }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```

Comment: Although i have other actions that return JSONRESULT and it works perfectly fine. Why would this alone cause an issue? The other actions i mentioned are also in the same controller and used in the same client page.

Comment: Perhaps they are being requested by a POST request. This does not require the JsonRequestBehavior

Comment: I did notice that the other request was JSON /List/GetContents HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1):

You're using data.ReaderName when your returned JSON object is singular.

You can either do:

```
public ActionResult Reader()
        {

            return Json(new 
            {
                data = new {
                   ReaderName = "First Floor",
                   Cardholder = "John, Doe"
                }
            });
        }
```

OR simply:

```
template:"ReaderName #= ReaderName #"
```

Comment: I tried this but no luck. Tried the second option the template.

Comment: Can you try the first option, too? With the data tag?

Comment: And can you look in firebug and see what the response is sending back?